# MySQL - selecting multiple values between characters in column as separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The following is loaded as one single field into a table. I realize this is bad design but it is a process out of my control. I would like to select multiple values within this field as separate columns. The query, result and desired result as follows:

Query: `Select theme from table1;`

Result:

```
"different LTs" is neutral (sentiment score: 0.245, relevancy: 4) "following LTs" is neutral (sentiment score: 0.245, relevancy: 4) "common lieutenants" is neutral (sentiment score: 0.245, relevancy: 4)
```

Desired result (As 3 separate columns):

```
theme1         | theme2        | theme3

different LTs  | following LTs | common lieutenants
```

How do i achieve this in SQL? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You have to use lots of `locate` and `substr` calls to extract each part of the string. If you do some searching, you may be able to find a regular expression UDF that you can use to make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an alternate answer only using `LOCATE` and `SUBSTRING` and it returns NULL when the quotations are not present (like for example if you have only theme1 and theme2, or if you only have theme1, or if you have no theme at all). you can try this crazy one ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8888a/30/0))

```
SELECT   theme,
   SUBSTRING(theme,IF(LOCATE('"',theme)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme))+1,
                   IF(LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1))-
                   IF(LOCATE('"',theme)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme))-1) as theme1,
   SUBSTRING(theme,IF(LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1))+1,
                   IF(LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)+1)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)+1))-
                   IF(LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1))-1) as theme2,
   SUBSTRING(theme,IF(LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)+1)+1)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)+1)+1))+1,
                   IF(LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1))-
                   IF(LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)+1)+1)=0,NULL,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme,LOCATE('"',theme)+1)+1)+1)+1))-1) as theme3
FROM table1
```

if you always have 3 themes then use the other answer, it's much cleaner :)

Comment: Works great!! I do in fact have rows where the total themes are not always 3 and have 2 and sometimes 1. So this works perfectly. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

If all values have the same form, then you can use this query -

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(theme, '"', 2), '"', -1)  theme1,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(theme, '"', 4), '"', -1)  theme2,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(theme, '"', 6), '"', -1)  theme3
FROM
  table1;
```

Comment: This works great when there are actually three themes, but when there is one and two and three are not available, it selects the characters that follow theme 1 as 2 and three. For example:
Theme1       |    Theme2   |Theme 3
forum users  |  is positive (sentiment score: 0.600, relevancy: 4) |
  is positive (sentiment score: 0.600, relevancy: 4)

Comment: @karthicks Yes, this query is very specific.